# I get an attribute error for header variable passed in the GET Request

Tags: python, get, attributeerror

I get an AttributeError when I try to pass the header for making a get request.

```
auth {"APIUsername":"username","APIPassword":"password"}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=auth, verify=False)
```

I have tried the auth header with single quotes and it seems to be working. But my credentials are are retrieved from elsewhere and the retrieved object has double quotes in it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\wss_logs_test4.py", line 102, in <module>
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=auth, verify=False)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 446, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Looks like `auth` is a string instead of a dict.

Comment: The code posted showing what is in `auth` is not valid Python; maybe it is meant to be assigning something to `auth`, but it is not.

Comment: I figured it out. I am now doing json.loads(auth) and it fixed it. Appreciate all the help :):)